Can I create a private route53 entry for a Opensearch VCP default endpoint
I have an OpenSearch Cluster running elasticsearch 7.4 and I want to create a route53 private endpoint but without creating a custom endpoint. I want to use it privately inside the vpc and with my AWS VPN the endpoint is with https but I want to redirect it to http is it possible ?
thanks
having a private dns pointing to my Opensearch default vpc domain

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
